# FTP using VSFTPD "Access Denied"

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, configuration, vsftpd

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 i386. I use Cyberduck (FTP GUI client) to connect to my server mysub.domainname.com (changed here).

**This is what I want to be able to do:**

1) Change apache2 root from `/var/www` to `/home/myuser/webroot` to serve files like index.html

2) Allow FTP to write in `/home/myuser/webroot`

3) Allow `myuser` to login with his user/pass combo with FTP and read/write anywhere within `myuser` folder

Apache2 root folder works fine. Going to myserver.com/index.html works. But I can't get FTP to write, even though I changed these lines in `etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
#local_umask=022
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#idle_session_timeout=600
#data_connection_timeout=120
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#async_abor_enable=YES
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#deny_email_enable=YES
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

**The problem**

Whenever I try to create a folder in `/home/myuser` or `/home/myuser/webroot` I get error `Create directory operation failed.` in my FTP program, Cyberduck.

Maybe helpful info:

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 myuser www-data 4096 2011-04-18 03:04 webroot
```

and I changed the permissions here too:

```
-rw-rwSr-- 1 myuser root 69 2011-04-18 02:14 index.html
```

...BUT no luck. I still can't upload or write using FTP. Any suggestions or pointers would be great, I'm pretty squarely lost on this one.

**UPDATE:**

I tried enabling anonymous logins for FTP, and I could not even get that to work...I think the only solution is to completely purge system of vsftpd and apache2 and just start over

Comment: Good question.  All the walkthroughs I find online are for virtual users rather than normal local users, so it seems that what you have should work.  What happens if you try uploading to a world-writable directory like /tmp ? If it works, who owns the file?

Comment: When I upload a file to /tmp, say "something.js" using Cyberduck logged in as myuser, it does work. The file is owned by myuser.

Comment: @lollercoaster might be SELinux.  What does `ls -ldZ /home/myuser/webroot/` say, and do you have any relevant messages in `/var/log/audit.log`?

Comment: `root@myserver:/# ls -ldZ /home/myuser/webroot
ls: cannot access /home/myuser/webroot: No such file or directory`

Comment: and no messages in `/var/log/audit.log` in fact there is no such file on my machine

Comment: Sorry, I had this window sitting here for a while so I didn't see the edit where you changed from webroot to htdocs, I'm updating my SSL answer with the complete answer.

Comment: oh no problem. i guess i dont need to change the names..not like anyone knows my domain or anything anyway. but ill just do it now to stay consistant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For permissions, you need to have the folder and files in it owned by `myuser` so that they can be accessed from the myuser account.

If apache (or your scripts) needs to **write** to the folder, then the best thing to do is use `chgrp` to assign the specific locations that should be written to to the www-data group, then `chmod g+w` that location or file.  If you are giving write access to a folder, `chmod g+sw` will give write access to the folder and ensure that files created there will also belong to the www-data group.

The files and directories in this case would look something like:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser   www-data    4096 2011-04-18 03:04 webroot
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   www-data    1000 2011-04-18 03:04 index.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 myuser   www-data    4096 2011-04-18 03:04 folderwithg+ws
```

You would want to be very careful giving write access to files and folders to apache though, otherwise an attacker might figure out a way to make your scripts overwrite themselves or replace index.html, or whatever.

Otherwise, if apache does not need to write to your document directory, the permissions should be fine as it is long as all of the subdirectories and files are world readable (and directories are world accessible).

For SSL/TLS, you're missing

```
ssl_enable=YES
```

You can force users to use encryption:

```
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
```

And there is a `ssl_ciphers=`  option as well, if you want to limit it to HIGH or a specific list of ciphers.  If you want "implicit SSL" (instead of `AUTH SSL` or `AUTH TLS` commands to start encryption, the encryption is negotiated at the beginning of the connection) then that is `implicit_ssl=YES`

Comment: OK, cool. So given that the webroot folder is owned by `root` and `www-data` as seen here: 

`root@myserver:/home/myuser# ls -l` returns 
`drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 4096 2011-04-18 03:04 webroot`

- then I should change ownership using `chown myuser webroot`. but that is still confusing, can I have both www-data and myuser still have ownership? I want to have the myuser folder and all of its subdirectories read/write capable for BOTH Apache and FTP. Is that possible?

Comment: @loller `www-data` is the owner, `root` is the group.  Standard Unix permissions are based on owner, group, then everyoneelse.  If the folder is owned by "myuser" and the first set of "rwx" is enabled, then myuser has read write and access/execute permissions.  If you change the group to www-data (ubuntu's default apache group) then use the chmod command I gave to enable group write access (second set of "rwx" is enabled (x will be "s" if you used g+sw)) then apache, being a member of www-data group, will be able to write to it.

Comment: not working. I'll update my original post to be clearer. I'm really not sure what the problem is - I still can't upload with FTP or create files

Comment: I wonder if it thinks you're using virtual users?  I can't really find a guide that explains what makes virtual users with PAM different from local users with PAM... try `virtual_use_local_privs=YES`

Comment: hmmmm. good thought, but it didn't seem to work either.